# View Profile page as another user in django

Tags: django, django-views

So I have a `my user profile` view you can see as a logged in user. I wanted to add a second view so other logged in users can visit profile pages as well, but I'm not really sure I'm doing it the right way

urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/profile/', main_views.uprofile, name='uprofile'), #the page you see as my profile
    url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', main_views.oprofile, name='oprofile'), # the page i use so other users can view the profile page
    url(r'^accounts/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/', User_Profile_views.edit_user, name='edit_user'), #Custom update profile page
```

main_views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def uprofile (request):

    context = locals()  
    template = 'profile.html'
    return render (request, template, context)

def oprofile (request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

    context = locals()  
    template = 'profile.html'
    return render (request, template, context)
```

Comment: This sounds very broad, but I'd imagine you just need to include some boolean in the template to hide any editing functionality

Comment: No one can edit since the logged in ID need to much the User ID ... and I'm looking for more efficient  way to do it.

Comment: I don't think you'll get any more efficient than a single boolean.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/arteria/django-hijack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From product point of view, you would want to keep same url for both `uprofile` and `oprofile`. One simple reason being, when I visit my profile and if I want to share it with someone else, I'd just copy-paste the url.

**How to do that?**

In your view, pass a flag that helps your template to render the right elements. For instance, if the user is same as the profile being visited, pass a flag, say `editable`, and use it to show edit buttons. And instead of two views, you can have single view.

Also, instead of id, people tend to remember their username/handle. So it's better to have username. However, make sure you have unique username for all users.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/$', main_views.profile, name='profile'),
```

**views.py**

```
def profile (request, username):
    # If no such user exists raise 404
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        raise Http404

    # Flag that determines if we should show editable elements in template
    editable = False
    # Handling non authenticated user for obvious reasons
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user == user:
        editable = True

    context = locals()
    template = 'profile.html'
    return render (request, template, context)
```